# I cannot convert character to date

Tags: r, date, character

I am importing this data

```
Dates<- read_xlsx("../spiros/DATA/excel/dates.xlsx")
```

which gives me those Dates, that they are characters

```
<$ Date              : chr [1:4001] "Jan 04, 2006" "Jan 05, 2006" "Jan 06, 2006" "Jan 0>
```

then I am trying to convert them to dates with this code

```
Dates$Date = as.Date(Dates$Date, format = "%b %d, %Y")
```

But I am getting `NA NA NA`

Can anyone understand what the problem is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have met the same situation..